# Creating Linked Child Item in Azure DevOps via Build Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, pipeline, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to create a build pipeline that creates a parent Feature in Azure DevOps along with several child User Stories that are linked to the parent Feature.

I have used an Azure DevOps extension for creating Work Items and I have successfully created a parent Feature via Build Pipeline - but I cannot figure out how to add more tasks in the build to create the child User Stories that are linked to the parent Feature.

N/A

Expected result is build completes successfully and parent Feature / linked child User Stories are created without issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#create-two-work-items-and-link-them) to do this. You can add a powershell task to the build pipeline job and then write the rest api to the script.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.0
```

Sample requset body:

```
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/XXX/_apis/wit/workItems/XXX",
      "attributes": {
        "comment": "Making a new link for the wit "
      }
    }
  }
```

You can also refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803566/how-to-create-child-tasks-under-existing-user-story-using-tfs-rest-api-in-c) for help .